# Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I used multiprocessing in Python to run my code in parallel, like the following,

```
result1 = pool.apply_async(set1, (Q, n))
result2 = pool.apply_async(set2, (Q, n))
```

set1 and set2 are two independent function and this code is in a while loop.

Then I test the running time, if I run my code in sequence, the for particular parameter, it is 10 seconds, however, when I run in parallel, it only took around 0.2 seconds. I used time.clock() to record the time. Why the running time decreased so much, for intuitive thinking of parallel programming, shouldn't be the time in parallel be between 5 seconds to 10 seconds? I have no idea how to analyze this in my report... Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: do you call `result1.get()` eventually? Have you checked that both variants (sequential/parallel) produce the same result? You could use `timeit.default_timer()` instead of `time.clock()`. Or just call it from command-line: `python -mtimeit -s "from your_module import setup, run; setup();" "run()"`

Answer (score 1):

To get a definitive answer, you need to show all the code and say which operating system you're using.

My *guess*:  you're running on a Linux-y system, so that `time.clock()` returns CPU time (not wall-clock time).  Then you run all the real work in new, distinct processes.  The CPU time consumed by those doesn't show up in the main program's `time.clock()` results at all.  Try using `time.time()` instead for a quick sanity check.